# How to display a value through an expression with the corresponding column in SSRS?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've been scouring the forums but to no avail and I need help with displaying a certain value with an expression. I have a table with this Dataset set:

Description | Value

```
     Var1  | 10

     Var2  | 20

     Var3  | 30

     Var4  | 40
```

I've been trying to make an Expression thru SSRS in a way where =IIF(Fields!Description.Value, "Var1") THEN (Display 10 here)

I can't figure out a way to display the corresponding value of the row associated with that dataset.

Hope I can get some help.

Regards,

MPatrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSRS the proper way to use the IIF function is this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Description.Value = "Var1", "10", "")
```

If the first parameter into the function evaluates as true, the second parameter is returned, otherwise the third parameter is returned.

If you are really trying to display a value from another dataset, you need a lookup.

```
=Lookup(Fields!Description.Value, Fields!Description.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "Dataset2")
```

What this is doing is trying to match the `Description` value in the current dataset to the same value in a second dataset named `Dataset2`, and returning the value in a field from `Dataset2` named `Value`. This may seem confusing, but your sample named the fields `Description` and `Value`, so I tried to keep with that.

This will work in a lookup, too.

```
=Lookup("Var1", Fields!Description.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "Dataset2")
```

In plain English: Give me the `Fields!Value.Value` in `Dataset2` where the `Fields!Description.Value` is equal to `Var1`.

Comment: The last answer you gave me worked perfectly! Thank you!